# Ubuntu 18.04 stutters after switching to prime-select intel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, intel-graphics, intel

I've read a lot problem where their system freezes on/after login after switching to prime-select intel, but in my case it doesn't freeze but it stutters.

Every few seconds the system stutters and sort of lag for around a second then back to smooth usage again.

Anybody experienced this? Any workaround for this problem?